# Postgres error ERROR: right sibling's left-link doesn't match

Tags: postgresql, psql

Im using postgres latest in a docker container, and fot some reason i got this error
and everything stop working:

```
The "postgresql" authentication provider has encountered an internal error which will halt the authentication process. If this is unexpected or you are the developer of this authentication provider, you may wish to enable debug-level logging. If this is expected and you wish to ignore such failures in the future, please set "skip-if-unavailable: postgresql" within your guacamole.properties.
ERROR o.a.g.rest.RESTExceptionMapper - Unexpected internal error:
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: right sibling's left-link doesn't match: block 2 links to 11010 instead of expected 11007 in index "guacamole_user_history_user_id"
### The error may involve org.apache.guacamole.auth.jdbc.user.UserRecordMapper.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: INSERT INTO guacamole_user_history (             remote_host,             user_id,             username,             start_date,             end_date         )         VALUES (             ?,             (SELECT user_id FROM guacamole_user              JOIN guacamole_entity ON guacamole_user.entity_id = guacamole_entity.entity_id              WHERE                    guacamole_entity.name = ?                AND guacamole_entity.type = 'USER'::guacamole_entity_type),             ?,             ?,             ?         )
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: right sibling's left-link doesn't match: block 2 links to 11010 instead of expected 11007 in index "guacamole_user_history_user_id"
```

And this is from postgres conatiner:

```
ERROR:  right sibling's left-link doesn't match: block 2 links to 11010 instead of expected 11007 in index "guacamole_user_history_user_id"
    STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO guacamole_user_history (
            remote_host,
              user_id,
                 username,
                 start_date,
                 end_date
             )
            VALUES (
                $1,
                 (SELECT user_id FROM guacamole_user
                  JOIN guacamole_entity ON guacamole_user.entity_id = guacamole_entity.entity_id
                 WHERE
                     guacamole_entity.name = $2
                     AND guacamole_entity.type = 'USER'::guacamole_entity_type),
                  $3,
                $4,
                  $5
         ) RETURNING *
```

I didnt do anything speciel to DB just a simple select querys at the time.
All worked for the last 3 months 
how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

This solved my issue:

```
REINDEX TABLE guacamole_user_history;
```

Comment: But you have suffered from corruption. Check your hardware! Dump and restore to a newly created cluster!

Comment: I ran atop\htop and all seems fine, what else can i check? it went back to working proprly, also again this is inside containers its not in the host database. i did recreated them multipul times

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working properly, and maybe everything is fine. But maybe there is some corruption lurking somewhere. Data corruption can spread. Are these data important to you?

Comment: Yes it is important, and i didnt do any backup

Comment: Well, then don't play with it. Do as I say. As a DBA I would say that the fact that you have no backup is a proof that the data are not really important...

Comment: It is important but its just the start of the project, i hope it will keep working fine, im not playing with the data by the way im just sending simple select statements. ill try again today and see if it causes it again and also preform a backup. thanks

Comment: Backup is essential, but if you plan to continue using the database, dump it and restore to a new cluster. Don't rest until you have found the cause of the corruption, else it is likely to recur.

Comment: How can i find out why it happand ?

Comment: Test the hardware, check if the database was restored (and if yes, check the procedures), check if there were crashes or weird log messages. It is more detective work than anything else. Bad memory or storage are the prime suspects.